# Show a login pop up again before saving a list item

Tags: login

When we open a SharePoint site it asks for user name and password. After entering the credentials the site gets opened.

My requirement is when we create a new list item, before saving it should again ask for login.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be the following:

1. Inject JavaScript code in the `New` form. This can be done by editing the list form in SharePoint Designer, or by adding the code in the master page (it would first check the current URL) or by adding a custom action in the list.
2. The JavaScript would delete all cookies (including authentication cookies). You can use code like the one proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/179514/3439544.

Note: this won't work for all other means you can add an item. For instance won't work for the Quick Edit mode, for addition with client API, etc.

Comment: You're welcome. It it helps, don't hesitate to officially mark it as "answered": that will please Danny: http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/20k-celebrations-or-do-we-want-to-cleanup-those-unanswered-questions?cb=1 :)